# I have two functions in my controller but when run admin/panel show error Undefined variable: labels

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have this error:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: labels

What should I do to return `$labels` in `getLastMonths()` method?

## panelcontroller

```
public function index()
   {
        $month=12;

        $peymentSuccess=Payment::SpanningPayment($month,true);

        $peymentunSuccess=Payment::SpanningPayment($month,false);

        $labels = $this->getLastMonths($month);// mahe shamsi bar migardoune nasbe jalali morilog

        $values['success']=$peymentSuccess->pluck('published');
        $values['unsuccess']=$peymentunSuccess->pluck('published');

        return view('admin.panel', compact('labels','values'));
   }

private function getLastMonths( $month)
    {
        for ($i=0 ; $i>$month ; $i++)
        {
            $labels[]=jdate(Carbon::now()->subMonths($i))->format('%B');
        }
        return $labels;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does:

```
$month=12;
// ...
$labels = $this->getLastMonths($month);
```

And then:

```
private function getLastMonths($month)
{
    for ($i=0 ; $i>$month ; $i++)
    // ...
```

This loop will never work - `$month` is 12, `$i` is 0, 0 is never greater than 12.  There will be no iterations, `$labels` is never set, and `getLastMonths()` returns nothing.

You need instead:

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < $month ; $i++)
```

Or maybe (depending on your requirements, I am not sure what you are exactly doing):

```
for ($i=0 ; $i <= $month ; $i++)
```

Comment: yeah thank you very much .I made a mistake in for loop:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not initilized $labels in the getLastMonths($month) function.
use following code.

```
private function getLastMonths( $month)
    {
        $labels = [];
        for ($i=0 ; $i<$month ; $i++)
        {
            $labels[]=jdate(Carbon::now()->subMonths($i))->format('%B');
        }
        return $labels;
    }
```